# Advanced topic in numerical solution of differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Investigate the stability of the PECE method where

P=Predictor : $y_{n+1} = y_n + hf(y_n)$

C=Corrector: $y_{n+1} = y_n + h [(1-θ) f(y_n) + θ f(y_(n+1))], (0<θ<1) $

and E is the evaluation step.

=>
substituting the predictor into corrector gives:
$$
y_{n+1} = y_n + h [(1-θ) f(y_n) + θf( y_n+ h f y_n )]\ \ \ \ (1)
$$
stability : $\frac{d}{dt}y = λy=f$

which has exact solution of $y(t)= y_0 e^{λt}$.

Substitute $f=λy$ into $(1)$:
$$
y_{n+1} = y_n + h [(1-θ) λ y_n + θλ( y_n+ h λy_n )]
$$
$$
y_{n+1} = y_n + h ( λ y_n-θ λ y_n + θλ y_n+ θh λ^2 y_n )
$$
$$
y_{n+1} = y_n + h ( λ y_n+ θh λ^2 y_n )
$$
$$
y_{n+1} = y_n + h λ y_n+ θ(h λ)^2 y_n 
$$
$$
y_{n+1} = y_n (1+ h λ+ θ(hλ)^2)
$$
now,

$$|1+ h λ+ θ(hλ)^2|<1$$
So:
$$
-1 < 1+ h λ+ θ(hλ)^2 < 1
$$

Kindly anyone help me after this , how to investigate the stability of PECE method

Comment: Could you add MathJax in your question? It is hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

Denote $z=h\lambda$, and solve the second order equation in $z$:
$$
1+z+\theta z^2<1,
$$
$$
1+z+\theta z^2>-1,
$$
Then, sub $z=h\lambda$ and find $\theta$. You will find an interval within wich you method will be stable.